# How to perform right Matrix-Vector with an array of Matrices and an array of vectors (numpy)

Tags: numpy

I have been trying to find a solution to this but can't seem to find it.

Without using a for-loop, I want to perform Matrix-Vector multiplication.

**let A be a N-m-n array of matrices and let B be a N-n array of vectors.**

The code equivalence is:

```
    # create a Nxn matrix as the output
    C = np.zeros(N, n)
    for N in range(A.shape[0]):
        C[N] =A[N] @ B[N]
```

The problem with simply doing `A @ B` is that numpy assumes B is a matrix instead of broadcasting the matrix-vector product.
Again, this is the Matrix multiplication in the column space of Matrix N and vector N.

I tried looking for an np.einsum and a np.tensordot solution, but can't seem to find one.

Comment: did you try `b[:,:,None]`?  so it is (N,n,1)

Comment: You don't want `tensodot`, but `einsum`  should be easy - you just have to understand the basics of the indexing.  'ijk,ik->ij', where 'k' is the sum-of-products dimension, your `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.einsum` should solve your problem.
If you have a N-array `A` of matrices `mxn` and a N-array of vectors `nx1`, C should be an N-array of vectors `mx1`. Then, to use `np.einsum` would be a matter of getting the correct indices.

For example, given

```
# these values are illustrative
N, m, n = 4, 5, 3 
A = np.random.randint(10, 100, (N, m, n))
B = np.random.randint(5, 10, (N, n))
```

Your code

```
C = np.empty((N, m)) # notice the dimension here is different from your code
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    C[i] = A[i] @ B[i]
```

can be rewritten using `np.einsum` by mapping the dimensions to the correct indices, as pointed out by @hpaulj
`Nxmxn`,`Nxn` -> `Nxm`
`i j k`,`i k` -> `i j`

```
C = np.einsum("ijk,ik->ij", A, B)
```

For more information on how to use `np.einsum`, you can find a nice explanation in this [link](https://ajcr.net/Basic-guide-to-einsum/).